# Keep accordion open on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

When I click on a heading in a Bootstrap according that's already open, I want the associated collapse to stay open.

How would I do this using Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: Please post what you've tried in a minimal, complete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do this is to remove the automatic show/hide by removing the `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute from your headings. Then add some Javascript to show them when the headings are clicked:

```
$('.collapsed').on('click', function() {
    var collapseItem = '#'+$(this).attr('aria-controls');
    $(collapseItem).collapse('show');
});
```

Example in action: http://www.bootply.com/RyVftggq0p

Comment: I'm not using data-toggle. I'm using data-parent. I should clarify that I want it to close when I click on another collapse heading, but not when I click on the one that's already open.

Comment: Then you can add in another line to the Javascript to close the other ones.

Comment: would that just be `$('.panel-group .panel-collapse').collapse('hide)`?

Comment: Without seeing your markup I can't say for sure but it looks OK.

Comment: I got it to work. At first, it was toggling, so I added `:not()` selector. Now it looks like `$('#menu .panel .panel-collapse:not(' + collapseItem + ')').collapse('hide');`